# Como realizar a quebra de linha de uma String dentro de uma célula no Excel com VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, office-open-xml

Como posso realizar a quebra de linha de uma String com várias cidades concatenadas para cada estado listado em uma célula de um Excel exportado em VB.NET e utilizando OfficeOpenXml e OfficeOpenXml.Drawing.

Trecho da Planilha:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Trecho do Código:

```
Dim nome_cidade As String = "São Paulo < br/> Guarulhos <br /> Campinas"
ws.Cells(cod_linha, cod_coluna).Value = nome_cidade                                                                ws.Cells(cod_linha, cod_coluna).StyleName = txt_estilo
cod_coluna += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Para tal basta substituir onde você está adicionando os `<br />` por `Environment.NewLine`

Exemplo:

```
Dim nome_cidade As String = string.Format("São Paulo {0} Guarulhos {0} Campinas", Environment.NewLine)
ws.Cells(cod_linha, cod_coluna).Value = nome_cidade                                                                
ws.Cells(cod_linha, cod_coluna).StyleName = txt_estilo
cod_coluna += 1
```